# Is there a way to create unique structs in a for-loop?

Tags: c

I've done some searching on Stack and Google and haven't found anything particularly useful, so I figured I'd make a new post.

Let's say I have the following struct:

```
typedef struct ItemToPurchase_Struct{

    char itemName[ITEM_NAME_MAX_SIZE];
    int itemPrice;
    int itemQuantity;
    
}ItemToPurchase;
```

Would there be a way to create a for-loop that could create new unique instances (if that's the correct term to use..I'm new to C and structs) of the given struct instead of manually having to create each one?

Thank you all, and hope you're doing well.

Comment: Do you want an (zero-initialized) array: `ItemToPurchase arr[10] = {0};`? Then, to set the first element you could do: `strcpy(arr[0].itemName, "first"); arr[0].itemPrice = 42; arr[0].itemQuantity = -1;` or set the last element: `strcpy(arr[9].itemName, "last"); ...`

Comment: @pmg I'm not asking how to set the values of the struct elements. I'm asking if there is a way to create new, unique structs of the same type in a for-loop.

Comment: You need to use `malloc()` to allocate them dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

For instance

```
ItemToPurchase * array[10];

for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    ItemToPurchase * item = malloc(sizeof(ItemToPurchase));
    array[i] = item;
}
```

Do what you want with the items and finally free them :

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) free(array[i]);
```

Comment: I've heard of malloc, but never used it. I'll take a look into that. Thank you for your help @dspr